# CMake compile-time defines

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am new to using CMake and am attempting to transfer our previous Makefiles into CMakeLists. I have one file, ***dsplink_defines.txt*** that has the following compile-time defines.

***-DOS_LINUX -DMAX_DSPS=1 -DMAX_PROCESSORS=2 -DID_GPP=1 -DOMAPL1XX -DPROC_COMPONENT -DPOOL_COMPONENT -DNOTIFY_COMPONENT -DMPCS_COMPONENT -DRINGIO_COMPONENT -DMPLIST_COMPONENT -DMSGQ_COMPONENT -DMSGQ_ZCPY_LINK -DCHNL_COMPONENT -DCHNL_ZCPY_LINK -DZCPY_LINK -DKFILE_DEFAULT -DDA8XXGEM -DDA8XXGEM_PHYINTERFACE=SHMEM_INTERFACE -DGPP_SWI_MODE -D_REENTRANT -DVERIFY_DATA -DDDSP_DEBUG***

Our previous Makefile took care of this in the following manner and took care of this by using ***shell cat*** starting on line 8:

```
BIN = ../../build/bin
TMP = build

BUILD_DEF = -DBUILD=$(BUILD_VERSION) -DBUILD_DATE=$(BUILD_DATE)

# these files are captured from the DSPLink Sample build directory (and the named      changed)
# they contain the appropriate includes and flags to build a dsplink application.
DSPLINK_INCLUDES = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_includes.txt)
DSPLINK_FLAGS = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_flags.txt)
DSPLINK_DEFINES = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_defines.txt)
DSPLINK_LIBS =          $(DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR)/dsplink/gpp/export/BIN/Linux/OMAPL1XX/RELEASE/dsplink.lib


#Our project variables
INCLUDE = -I../framework -I../io_master -I../logging -I../../dsp/include -      I../flagDictionary


#TOOLCHAIN = ${FACTORY_DIR}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/bin
TOOLCHAIN = /OMAP-L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin
PLATFORM=armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi

#Compile Options
CC=$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)-g++
LINKER=$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)-g++
CFLAGS+= $(BUILD_DEF) $(INCLUDE) $(DSPLINK_DEFINES) $(DSPLINK_FLAGS)     $(DSPLINK_INCLUDES)
DEBUG = -O

#list of things to compile.
FW_BUILD_DIR=../framework/build
LOG_BUILD_DIR=../logging/build
FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR=../flagDictionary/build

FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS= $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/com.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/application.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/memoryManagerBase.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/memoryManager.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/arguments.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/lockManager.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/controlCom.o \
       $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/paths.o \
       $(LOG_BUILD_DIR)/subsystemLogMasks.o \
       $(LOG_BUILD_DIR)/logger.o

FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS= $(FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR)/flagEntry.o \
               $(FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR)/flagDictionary.o

OBJECTS = spidev_test.o sysMon.o 
EXES = sysMon

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXES)

.c.o:
mkdir -p build
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) -o $(TMP)/$@ $< 

.cpp.o:
mkdir -p build
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) -o $(TMP)/$@ $< 

spidev_test: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) spidev_test.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/spidev_test.o       $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)


sysMon: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) sysMon.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/sysMon.o    $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

deploy:
../../build/deploy
```

How do I pass these in using a CMakeList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
file(READ path/to/dsplink_defines.txt defines) #read file into variable 'defines'
string(REPLACE " " ";" defines "${defines}") #turn space separation into CMake list
add_definitions(${defines})
```

Of course, if you have full control of the file and can change its format to use semicolons for separation instead of spaces, you can do that and skip the `string()` line (probably speeding up your CMake processing a little bit by this).

Comment: Since each subdirectory of the {CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} will use these would I place this in the top level CMakeList or in the CMakeList in each subdirectory?

Comment: Quoting the docs of `add_definitions()`: "Adds flags to the compiler command line for sources in the current directory and below." This means you can do it once in the toplevel dir, or in each of the subdirs, your choice.

Comment: This definitely worked! Thank you so much...I had been working on this all morning.